# $T:V\rightarrow V, $ prove that if $ker(T) ∩ im(T)\ne \{0\},$ then $dim(Ker(T^2))≥2$

Tags: linear-algebra

so far ive managed to come with:

$$\dim(\ker(T)+\text{im}(T))=\dim(\ker(T)+\dim(\text{im}(T))-\dim(\ker(T)\cap \text{im}(T))$$
based on these two rules

1. $$\dim(u+v)+\dim(u\cap v)=\dim(u)+\dim(v)$$
2. $$\dim(\ker(T)+\text{im}(T))=\dim(\ker(T))+\dim(\text{im}(T))$$

and i think i made some mistakes but would love help.

Comment: In Rule 1, what are $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ ? Vectors ? Note that Rule 1 is a rule about vector spaces. More precisely, if $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then $\dim(A+B)=\dim(A)+\dim(B)-\dim(A \cap B).$ You can't take dimensions of vectors (which is what you have seemingly written)

Comment: The edit by Nik changed it.  The original had !=0, i.e. $\ne \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $v \in \text{ker}(T) \cap \text{im}(T)$, what can you say about $T^2 u$ where $v = Tu$?

Comment: does it mean that the dim(T^2) = dim(ker(T)∩im(T))^2?

Comment: @shimmygoldsmith omg no! dim(T^2) doesn't even make sense and don't just randomly guess.. $v=Tu$(since $v$ in $\Im(T)$) implies $Tv=T^2u$, but $v \in \ker(T)$ so...?